# char-fold-search match for German eszett (ß)?

Tags: unicode, isearch

In emacs 25.1, if I customize **search-default-mode** to "Char-Fold Search", then an **isearch-forward** for

`u` matches `ü`

and one for

`o` matches `ö`.

But what character should I type to match `ß` ?

Answer (score 6):

By default, this is not possible (easiest way to see this is with `C-h v char-fold-table RET` and searching for ß — which you won't find).

However, if you modify `char-fold-table` (the variable responsible for determining how folding occurs), then you can enable this.

## The structure of `char-fold-table`

`char-fold-table` is a char-table — quoting the [emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Char_002dTable-Type.html):

> A char-table is a one-dimensional array of elements of any type, indexed by character codes.

In this case, the "elements" are regular expressions for what the given character is supposed to match when Char-Fold Search is on (i.e. more-or-less a list of the characters that are the same as the given character). For instance, by default, the element corresponding to s, obtained with:

```
(char-table-range char-fold-table ?s)
```

(or just `(aref char-fold-table ?s)` is:

```
"\\(?:s[̧̣̦́̂̇̌]\\|[sśŝşšſșˢṡṣₛⓢｓ]\\)"
```

`char-fold-table` also has an "extra slot", which is itself a char-table, and which lists the character combinations (*starting with the given letter*) that should match specific regexps (e.g. `fi` should match the unicode character `ﬁ`). For instance, the alist corresponding to f, found using:

```
(aref (char-table-extra-slot char-fold-table 0) ?f)
```

is:

```
(("fl" . "ﬄ") ("fi" . "ﬃ") ("l" . "ﬂ") ("i" . "ﬁ") ("f" . "ﬀ") ("m" . "㎙") ("̇" . "ḟ"))
```

which means that `ffl` should match `ﬄ`, `ffi` `ﬃ`, `fl` `ﬂ` etc.

## Having eszett matched by `ss`

This is probably the most logical possibility. To make this possible, we need to modify the alist in the extra slot of the `char-fold-table` to also contain `("s" . "ß")`:

```
(set-char-table-extra-slot
 char-fold-table 0
 (let* ((multi-char-table (char-table-extra-slot char-fold-table 0))
    (s-alist (aref multi-char-table ?s))
    (modified-s-alist (cons '("s" . "ß") s-alist)))
   (aset multi-char-table ?s modified-s-alist)
   multi-char-table))
```

Unfortunately, searching isn't too smooth, since sometimes you need to jog isearch, by pressing `C-s` again, after typing the entire search string, to convince it that the search is not actually failing (the same issue occurs with the default combinations).

(To see the issue, insert `gru grüßen` in a fresh buffer, place the mark at the start and try to search for `grussen`, typing — *not* copy-pasting — the search string. After you've typed `grus`, isearch concludes that the search is failing and won't do anything more unless prompted. An equivalent problem, using the default configuration would be with `an aﬃne` and searching for `affine`.)

## Having eszett matched by just `s`

```
(aset char-fold-table ?s "\\(?:s[̧̣̦́̂̇̌]\\|[sśŝşšſșˢṡṣₛⓢｓß]\\)")
```

Note the `ß` inserted into the end of the default regexp.

In principle, you could do both, partially circumventing the above mentioned issue.

## Is this a bug?

If you believe that the absence of eszett in the default `char-fold-table` is a bug, you could report it.

The reason why it's absent is because `char-fold-table` is automatically generated from the Unicode list of decomposable characters and Unicode believes that `ß` does not "decompose" into `s` + `s` in the same way that `á` does decompose into `a` + `accute accent`:

http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt

(search for: `LATIN SMALL LETTER SHARP S`).

Comment: Thanks for the (very thorough).  I'll report this as a bug, but in the meantime, I'm using your answer to match 'ß' with 's'.